# Why is Google indexing the title and description of my site in English instead of Portuguese?

Tags: google-search-console, search-engine-indexing, title, meta-description, translation

When I look for my website (in Portuguese, my language), Google shows me the title and description of the page in English and they appear to have indexed the Portuguese URL.

Why is this happening? I want to see the title and description in Portuguese when I search for `Olifel`. I have tried many things but nothing works. The meta description and title tag on each language page are the same but translated, so I don't think that's the issue.

[image]

Comment: The Googlebot primarily crawls from US based IP addresses and will index the content in your `/en` version (which does match the SERP) - see:  [How Google crawls locale-adaptive pages](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/specialty/international/locale-adaptive-pages). If you want to see results from your default language (Portuguese), make sure you don't use geolocation, and be sure to access `google.pt` from an IP address located in a Portuguese speaking region.

Comment: Also, you can try setting [x-default](https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2013/04/x-default-hreflang-for-international-pages) in the `hreflang` attribute value for your Portuguese pages, and make sure the `hreflang` for the alternative versions point to the correct language versions of your site. See [this](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/specialty/international/managing-multi-regional-sites?sjid=6277868394853427697-NA) and [this](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/specialty/international/localized-versions) for more.

Comment: My website IP is from United Kingdom, could  it be because of that?

Comment: Yes, along with several other factors. See [How Google determines the language of search results](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/13511324?hl=en#zippy=%2Clocation-and-region-settings) and [Understand & manage your location when you search on Google](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/179386).