# Google is not choosing the canonical URL I chose

Tags: google-search-console, canonical-url

My website already has a canonical URL defined however in the
Google Search Console it says that the canonical URL is the English page. How can I change this?
[image]
[image]

Comment: See the comments in your [previous](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/142791/why-is-google-indexing-the-title-and-description-of-my-site-in-english-instead-o) question. Make sure your site's code and server aren't doing geolocation, and that your `hreflang` attributes are set correctly.

Answer (score 3):

I visited your page.

- It doesn't show any canonical tag
- Automatically redirects to the english page
- It doesn't have any hreflang attributes

You have to fix all these things if you want the Portuguese language as your main  language.

Comment: The site has these hreflang attributes:

<link data-n-head="1" data-hid="i18n-alt-en" rel="alternate" href="https://olifel.pt/en" hreflang="en">
<link data-n-head="1" data-hid="i18n-alt-en-US" rel="alternate" href="https://olifel.pt/en" hreflang="en-US">
<link data-n-head="1" data-hid="i18n-alt-en" rel="alternate" href="https://olifel.pt/" hreflang="en">
<link data-n-head="1" data-hid="i18n-alt-pt-PT" rel="alternate" href="https://olifel.pt/" hreflang="pt-PT">
<link data-n-head="1" data-hid="i18n-xd" rel="alternate" href="https://olifel.pt/" hreflang="x-default">

Are any missing?

Comment: No it doesn't. I get none of these in the content.

Comment: Don't you see that when you inspect the website?

Comment: the same resuly of checking  `view-source:https://olifel.pt/` as @symcbean